# InvalidOperationException on client side while trying to deserialize parameter. WCF DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm having big trouble getting rid of this exception. The bad thing is, that it doesn't happen all the time. I get it pretty often on my XP machines though. I can't seem to find anything on google about this and I don't know anymore where I should look to find the error. We're using nettcpbinding and wcf datacontractserializer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the full exception being thrown when calling a method of my WCF service:

```
2013-02-18 08:35:04.6718 Service 2080 => Error while calling service System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://mydomain/product/Machine:GetBaysResult.  Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SR.GetString(String name, Object[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.CriticalHelper.ReadValue(Type type, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.CriticalHelper.ReadMembers(ClassDataContract classContract, Boolean[] requiredMembers, Label[] memberLabels, LocalBuilder memberIndexLocal, LocalBuilder requiredIndexLocal)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.CriticalHelper.ReadMembers(ClassDataContract classContract, LocalBuilder extensionDataLocal)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.CriticalHelper.ReadClass(ClassDataContract classContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.CriticalHelper.GenerateClassReader(ClassDataContract classContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.get_XmlFormatReaderDelegate()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfBayInfoFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Iproduct.GetBays(Guid sessionId)
   at product.Service.Client.productClient.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<GetBays>b__1c()
   at product.Service.Client.productClient.Invoke[T](Func`1 func)
```

The traces I got from the ServiceModel don't really help either:

```
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
at System.ServiceModel.SR.GetString(String name, Object[] args)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientDuplexConnectionReader.CreateProcessActionActivity()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientDuplexConnectionReader.DecodeMessage(Byte[] buffer, Int32&amp; offset, Int32&amp; size, Boolean&amp; isAtEOF, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.DecodeMessage(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
</StackTrace>
```

Comment: Is there any data that could be culture sensitive and will get on the wire in a bad format?

Comment: The error `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` message is indicative of a an `IEnumerable` being changed within a `foreach` loop (if not calling `GetEnumerator` explicitly - could this be user-code doing so conditionally? If not, may be a hiccup in the serialization mechanism of WCF.

Comment: Yes, but I handle this in a custom string format. Would this lead to an error like "Collection was modified;"?

Comment: The thing is, it happens when I call a method of the service. And it's not a FaultException that I get (so I'm sure it doesn't happen on the server side). It happens on different calls too. When I delay a call to be executed only when the given window shows the exception will be thrown on an earlier call.

Comment: Can you attach source code of GetBays method and GetBaysResult class ? Possibly deserialization code on client side modifies some collection which is already in enumeration loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidOperationException When calling ResourceManager.GetString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363057/invalidoperationexception-when-calling-resourcemanager-getstring)