# InvalidOperationException When calling ResourceManager.GetString

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My application throw the exception occasionally:

> Exception type: InvalidOperationException  Exception message:
>   Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

And here's stacktrace

```
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
```

And here's my code:

```
public IList<Function> MapWithLanguage(IList<Function> list)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var currentResource = Type.GetType("Fanex.Athena.Models.ViewModel.Menu, Fanex.Athena.Models");
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(currentResource);
    var newList = new List<Function>();
    foreach (var func in list)
    {
        newList.Add(new Function
        {
            Name = rm.GetString("Menu_" + func.FunctionId),
        });
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Anybody can help?it's so weird!

Comment: Do share from where this exception has been generated.

Comment: I have just updated my code!, please have a look @Backs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long time checking, I found the root cause.
And here's my code cause above issue:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().
```

Because this method try to load generated assemblies such as "web_adg_gfgt_dfd.dll" and they can be removed when IIS recycle .So to fix it we only need to avoid loading "generated assemblies".

Therefore we have 2 way for fixing:

1.Filter "generated assemblies":

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(i => i.IsDynamic == false).ToList()
```

2.Using this method :

```
BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().ToList()
```

Comment: Nice catch! It would be even nicer if someone at MS could verify if this is really related to the issue with the `ResourceManager.GetString` error, and if it's a bug in the .net 4 runtime. I at least didn't have this issue when targeting .net 2 runtime. Only started seeing this after switching from target framework 3.5 to 4.6. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Nguyen, I don't see "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()" in your code snipet from question

Comment: I have the same exception but don't call AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

Comment: @cosset if you don't load assemblies dynamically, your issue is not the same as mine

Comment: I don't see how the .Where() condition can help. GetAssemblies() loads an array so the dynamic assemblies will get loaded regardless. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: This answer is very tantalising but doesn't seem to actually give the answer.  If all we are calling is `ResourceManager.GetString`, how do we control the assemblies in the AppDomain?

Answer (score -2):

Actually InvalidOperationException Exception message: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute means:

We are changing the elements in the collection while looping over it with foreach.

I think this should solve your problem.

```
foreach (var func in list.ToList())
{
//Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: The answer is  unlikely relevant to the particular error.